# Calculate Euclidean Distance Between Two Points Using Constructor

Tags: java, class, constructor, double, euclidean-distance

I'm working on an assignment to write a java program which implements a Point data type with the following constructor:

Point(double x, double y, double z)

and, the following API:

- double distanceto(Point q)
  it returns the Euclidean distance between this and q.
  The Euclidean distance between (x1, y1, z1) and (x2, y2, z2) is defined as sqrt( (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2) + (z1-z2)^2).
- String toString() – it returns the string representation of the point. An example would be (2.3,4.5,3.0).
- Write a main method in the class that is used to test it.
  It should create two Point objects using input provided by the user on the command-line.
  Then it should print out the two points followed by their Euclidean distance
  A sample run would be as follows.

java Point 2.1 3.0 3.5 4 5.2 3.5

The first point is (2.1,3.0,3.5)

The second point is (4.0,5.2,3.5)

Their Euclidean distance is 2.90

The program won't compile, but I'm not sure why. I'm new to programming, so I followed some steps from online and Codecademy to try and access objects in the constructor, but I think I'm doing it wrong. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Point {
    double x1;
    double y1;
    double z1;
    double x2;
    double y2;
    double z2;
    
    public Point(double x, double y, double z){

        x1 = x;
        y1 = y;
        z1 = z;
        x2 = x;
        y2 = y;
        z2 = z;
    }
    
    public double distanceTo(Point q){
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x1-x2), 2.0) + Math.pow((y1-y2), 2.0) + Math.pow((z1-z2), 2.0));
    
    }
    double x3 = x1-x2;
    double y3 = y1-y2;
    double z3 = z1-z2;

    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x3 + ", " + y3 + ", " + z3 + ")";
    }
    
    public static void main (String[]args){
        
        Point pointOne = new Point(args[0]);
        Point pointTwo = new Point(args[1]);
        Point distance = new distanceTo();
        
        System.out.println("The first point is " + "(" + pointOne + ")");
        System.out.println("The second point is " + "(" + pointTwo + ")");
        System.out.println("Their Euclidean distance is " + distance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

First, you should only need one set of variables for your Point class. Just make one set and construct two point objects.

In the distanceTo() method, access the other point's coordinates by doing q.x1, q.y1, and so on.

In the main method, distance should be double that's pointOne's distance to pointTwo.
Here's the code that worked for me

```
class Point {
    double x1;
    double y1;
    double z1;
    public Point(double x, double y, double z){
    //each point object only needs one x, y and z
        x1 = x;
        y1 = y;
        z1 = z;
    }

    public double distanceTo(Point pointTwo){
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pointTwo.x1-x1, 2.0) + Math.pow(pointTwo.y1-y1, 2.0) + Math.pow(pointTwo.z1-z1, 2.0));
        //formula is sqrt((p2.x-p1)^2 + (p2.y-p1.y)^2 + (p2.z - p1.z)^2
    }


    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x1 + ", " + y1 + ", " + z1 + ")";
        //we don't need a diff set of variables here
    }

    public static void main (String[]args){
        //make two diff points with coords
        Point pointOne = new Point(2.1, 3.0, 3.5);
        Point pointTwo = new Point(4.0,5.2, 3.5);
        double distance = pointOne.distanceTo(pointTwo);
        //uses point two as the parameter (x2, y2, z2 in formula)
        System.out.println("The first point is " + "(" + pointOne + ")");
        System.out.println("The second point is " + "(" + pointTwo + ")");
        System.out.println("Their Euclidean distance is " + distance);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting a lot of errors when I try to compile my code. I just started learning about creating your own data types, so I'm a bit lost. If you could share some code, that would be awesome!

Comment: Ok, just added my code that worked, let me know if you need an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ended up figuring out the code right before I saw this post. We ended up with pretty much the same result. Your tips definitely helped me finalize my program, so much appreciated!